ngrok redirects to localhost instead of ngrok-url in ajax callback (ASP.NET project)
I have an ASP.NET project. I'm using NGROK to access and test the project remotely, mainly because I'm testing a webhook so my project needs to be callable from an external source.
Every normal HTML-anchor takes me to the next page fine, even when i'm using a form to Post data to a controller action. However, there are instances where I have to post an entire object, so i'll use an ajax call instead of a form. In the callback of this ajax call, I will go to the next by setting: window.location.href = result.url;
I see my browser redirect from the ngrok-url to localhost:xxx every time. I thought it was curious that (html)anchors worked fine but not when you're accessing a path in a callback.
So far I've tried to add an anchor to the DOM with the result.url as the href and click it programmatically, but the result stays the same.
I've also tried to add the following headers to the ajax call;
{
"Content-Type": "application/json", "ngrok-skip-browser-warning": "true",
Origin: window.location.origin
}
I've had no luck with these. Does anyone know what is happening and what the difference for NGROK is between clicking an anchor in the DOM or doing so in an ajax call?
All help is greatly appreciated!

I managed to resolve my issue!
So after two days of research, trial and error, i figured out a similar issue; as I said the anchor works fine, but going to a url manually, for example ngrok-url/my-url gave me the same problem (redirect to localhost:xxx/my-url).
How i finally managed to fix it, is use my network tab and compare the two call headers. I saw that the anchors automatically add a '/' after the page, so '/my-url/' instead of '/my-url'. To my surprise, after adding this last '/' everything worked fine. Don't understand how this fixed everything, but it did!
